# How to find the most frequent word in column B for a value in column A in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has a session value in column A with the name of a person that performed a task in column B. I would like to create a formula that will analyze the names in column B and determine who performed the most tasks for each session in column A.

[image]

For this example, I would like the results in column C to return the value "Will" for the rows 2 through 6, as Will performed the most actions for Session 5726.

I have tried using the MODE function, but I believe that only returns numeric values, rather than text values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most optimus way to not make multiple calculations is to create a Query in an auxiliary column:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"Select A,B,Count(B) group by A,B order by Count(B) desc")
```

[image]

Then with VLOOKUP you'll be able to find the first value of that session (which means the max because it is ordered by the count of B):

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A:A,D:E,2,0)))
```

[image]